# Is It Possible to Print the Current Collection's ORDER BY information?

Tags: module, magento-1, collection, debug

I've created a custom sort module that I'm attempting to debug. I'm curious if it is possible to display this information somewhere in my catalog pages (e.g. `app/code/design/package/theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`). Here is the observer portion of my custom module where I define the setOrder:

```
<?php

class MyExtension_CustomSort_Model_Observer
{
    public function onLoadCollection($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();

        $collection->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
            ->setOrder('name', 'asc');

        return true;
    }
}
```

I've tried echoing and using `print_r` to display my information but it seems I'm doing wrong. Any advice? The end result would be for me to see `created_at` and `name` somewhere near the top of page.

Comment: If you want to use the echo to debug if your extension is working or not, you can add a die(here) from your observer and you will see if it is being called. It will be a blank screen with "here" as the only content.

Comment: The reason your order statement is not showing is due to the order being added when the collection is actually loaded. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better yet, log the collection's query to a separate file. Or you can just do what mbalparda suggested, as well. The order statement gets incorporated only when the collection is loaded.

To examine the full query,

```
// After what you have posted..
$collection->load(true);   // ordering is set when the collection is loaded; see ref.
Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->__toString());  // prints the query to var/log/system.log
```

**Note**: Make sure to remove `->load(true)` after you're done debugging.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207240/get-collection-query-string

Comment: Ah, you were typing a similar answer as well ;)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you musicliftsme! Much more appropriate than what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a `die()` statement is a good pick. If you want to see how your `setOrder` behaves in the Magento query that is being generated for you, you can use the `$collection->getSelect()` method to get a dump of the SQL query. You can then echo the output of `getSelect()` to your screen or perhaps log it to the Magento system log using `Mage::log('My query: '.$collection->getSelect());`.

If you're having issues with the `name` and `created_at` attributes to appear in your query, you might need to add them to the query using `$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'created_at'))`.

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Even better yet, force log the collection into whatever log page you want.  Or you can just do what musicliftsme suggested, as well.

```
Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->__toString(),null,'thisfile.log',true); // prints the query to var/log/thisfile.log
```